# Can I use jQuery list view re order in titanium studio for android app?

Tags: jquery, titanium

I am working with Titanium studio, to develop android app, I want to implement  my list view rows reordering like http://jqueryui.com/sortable/ this. how can I implement this? any examples or suggestions.

If yes do I need to import jquery libraries to my app? how can I do that?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please check http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/66341/android-moveedit-rows

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is library designed to simplify operations on HTML but Titanium SDK is not using HTML to create views. It has it's own set of objects and their API to interact with a user. Because of that most of jQuery features are useless.

If you are creating app for iOS you can check [TableView object with moving property set to true](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-property-moving) and associated event [moveable](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-property-moveable). It's native component supported for iOS with functionality which you are looking for.

For more examples it's good to download and test [Kitchen Sink](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/ui/handheld/ios/baseui/table_view_move.js) application with various examples how you can build your mobile app.

Comment: Thanks your response and guiding. Here I am using android app. I saw moveable property is for only IOS, is anything for Android?

Comment: As far as I know Android doesn't have support for such feature in it's TableView implementation, so you have to code it by yourself. You could search if somebody created some module providing that feature but after some quick search I couldn't find anything.